# Sort input file according to first column, no delimiters but spaces

Tags: python, sorting, split, lines

I'm a Python beginner and trying to post process the a long txt file which is a list without delimiters, only spaces. I wanna sort it according to the first column.

The code compiles fine, but it only sorts my output file according to the very first value in the first column, but not according to the number itself. I also tried itemgetter operator without success.

I have tried this for hours now and hope anyone can help me. Why does my line split function not have the effect that I want?

```
f = open("traj_nvt_20000000.txt","r+") 
lines = f.readlines() for line in f.readlines():
line = line.strip()
parts = line.split(" ")
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: line[0])
with open('test123.txt', 'w') as text:
    text.writelines(lines)
```

An excerpt of the text file table that I want to sort:

```
54 2 -9.5377 -4.02842 -7.51558 7
55 2 -9.6834 -4.88656 -7.29358 7
459 2 -8.76522 -8.30942 -10.144 58
50 1 -9.33774 -4.46175 -7.24097 7
56 2 -8.84618 -4.59922 -7.44773 7
462 2 -10.3377 -9.37008 -10.2265 58
460 2 -8.59323 -8.64832 -9.32914 58
457 1 -8.96511 -8.38283 -9.63619 58
461 2 -9.0727 -7.89321 -9.40869 58
369 1 -5.93643 -6.20083 -7.56102 47
504 2 -7.94033 -2.66938 -10.3925 63
371 2 -6.24752 -6.57434 -7.3023 47
```

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have to sort as numerical, not alphanumerical, so convert your string to integer or float (I don't have all your data, I'm not sure if they're all integers):

```
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: float(line[0]))
```

but it would be even better to sort on all the values by returning a tuple of floats so if first values are equal, the rest can be used to discriminate:

```
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: [float(x) for x in line])
```

BTW your sample code is incorrect (there's a mix of readlines & loops at the start which does not work). Here's a small test which works:

```
f = open(r"U:\test.txt","r")  # sample file in the question
lines=[]
for line in f:
    lines.append(line.strip().split(" "))
f.close()

lines.sort(key=lambda line: [float(x) for x in line])
for l in lines:
    print(",".join(l))
```

result:

```
50,1,-9.33774,-4.46175,-7.24097,7
54,2,-9.5377,-4.02842,-7.51558,7
55,2,-9.6834,-4.88656,-7.29358,7
56,2,-8.84618,-4.59922,-7.44773,7
369,1,-5.93643,-6.20083,-7.56102,47
371,2,-6.24752,-6.57434,-7.3023,47
457,1,-8.96511,-8.38283,-9.63619,58
459,2,-8.76522,-8.30942,-10.144,58
460,2,-8.59323,-8.64832,-9.32914,58
461,2,-9.0727,-7.89321,-9.40869,58
462,2,-10.3377,-9.37008,-10.2265,58
504,2,-7.94033,-2.66938,-10.3925,63
```

Comment: Seems like you would need to split the line for ```line[0]``` to refer to the first *column* rather than the first character.

Comment: `line[0]` is already the first column (check my reproducer, the OP code is a bit, say ... fuzzy. You get the idea but it doesn't work)

Comment: @wwii: you're not guilty of anything. The OP pasted a confusing code. But the case he exposes is a classic: alphanum sort vs num sort: I challenge my trainees each time with that example.